# Java noob for each loop

Tags: java

I have tried researching to see what I can find. Im running into a problem with the for each method. What im doing is making a double array, and trying to iterate through each element for each array. I keep getting a error *Compilation Errors Detected

Line: 23
class, interface, or enum expected*

Another problem I am facing is the concept of why does this method fail, where is my logic wrong?? I appreciate you taking your time to read this, as im struggling with some basics.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
       String[][]nameAdress={{"kn", "vilon"},{"new house","old house"}};
       meth(nameAdress);
  }

  public static void meth(String[][] name){
       for(String[] names: name){
          for(String field: names){
            System.out.println(names);
          }
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: "double array" -> very unlucky choice of words. A `double`-array is normally understood to be an array of `double`values (i.e. `double[]`). What you have is a two-dimensional array of `String`s (or, to be more precise an array of `String`-arrays). Also, if you have a compiler error, please indicate which line exactly causes the error (e.g. through a comment in your source code). "why does this method fail" -> What do you mean by "fail"? Do you get an exception? Does it behave differently than you expected? Please be more precise and verbose.

Comment: my apologize i removed all comments, thanks

Comment: "Line: 23 class, interface, or enum expected" The code you have shown doesn't have 23 lines. Please indicate the line on which the error occurs. Additionally, [that code runs fine](https://ideone.com/SreCBU): in what way doesn't it do what you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this ,now its working fine

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World");

String[][]nameAdress={{"karn dhillon", "vinny dhillon"},{"new house","old house"}};
meth(nameAdress);
}

public static void meth(String[][] name){
    for(String[] element: name){
        for(String field: element){
            System.out.println(field);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @DheerajJoshi first of all, please fix the indentation of your code. Second, the first code block does not contain any compilation error, thus there was no error to fix.

Comment: String[] element and element are same because,when we are using String[] element for the first time we are initializing it, when we are using it again without String[] we dont have to initialize it again

Comment: you can read it like this,**for each String element field in the String array element print  the value of field**

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the order in the head of the foreach loop

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");



    String[][]nameAdress={{"karn dhillon", "vinny dhillon"},{"new house","old house"}};
    meth(nameAdress);
  }

  public static void meth(String[][] name){
    for(String[] element: name){
     for(String eachElement: element){
      System.out.println(eachElement);
     }
    }

  }

}
```